# Node.js learning guide or study plan

Tags: node.js

I am a PHP developer trying her hands on node.js. The introductory books about it and online tutorials are great and are helping me come to speed with this language
however I find the official site [nodejs.org](http://nodejs.org) documentation hard to drill through for somewhat reasons I don't understand, may be I am just spoiled by [php.net](http://php.net).
For example many asynchronous functions take a callback function with arguments and docs document that fact but the types of arguments these callbacks take are barely (not) documented

See below

```
fs.readFile('./template.html', function(err, data) {
 if (err) {
   console.error(err);
   res.end('Server Error');
}
else {
 var tmpl = data.toString(); 
}
});
```

Here the `data` argument appears to be an object with `toString` method and that's all I know about it.
Old langange users can you please point or guide me on how to get the most out of this nice langange, it can be anything such as how to read the docs.
Thank you.

Comment: try yourself, put debugger inside any function body and inspect `arguments`

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_file_options_callback) for node.js seem clear to me.

> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the contents of the file.